# How to setup AEM 6.5 on Premise

Tags: aem, aem-6, on-premises-instances

is there anyone who knows the step by step on how to setup AEM on Premise? I know how AEM as a cloud to setup in cloud manager but setting up the AEM instance outside the adobe cloud is quite difficult as I can't find any documentation on how to do it in the azure or aws cloud server.

We have our own server and we have to install AEM 6.5 on it with one author instance and 2 publish instance.

I tried to find documentations on how to setup AEM on premise or AEM instance in our own server but we cannot find anything.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! if you haven't, please take a [tour] and learn [ask]. asking for an external resources such as unofficial guide tend to be shunned upon. have you tried to get in touch with AEM's support? generally AEM on premise setup will need: 1) the AEM Author; 2) AEM Publish; 3) AEM Dispatcher (can use Apache or IIS choose which ever fits your needs)

Comment: Thank you so much for this info Tesa this is a good start, I will review as well the links above.

Comment: i checked, AEM 6.5 docs got guide on [how to setup the development environment](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/cloud-service/local-development-environment-set-up/aem-runtime.html?lang=en). i think they are enough to setup the AEM Author and Publish. you could consult another docs for [setting up the dispatcher](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/dispatcher.html?lang=en), its a lot more complicated and you might need to write extensive ruleset for the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

You need the JAR to setup the author and publish instances plus a license file provided by Adobe. The dispatcher module can also be downloaded from the Software Distribution portal. Of course, you need JDK8/JDK11 installed. Additionally, there are some differences between AEM Sites and installing AEMaaCS for local development, make sure what exactly do you want to setup, but the overall process is very similar.